# Bash auto-completion with added spaces – why, and how to fix?

Tags: bash

I use tab completion more than typing letters. I used to type `rm ~/De<TAB>` and it would be completed to `rm ~/Desktop/` so that I could continue on the next level.

Recently, that behaviour changed. The completion now yields `rm ~/Desktop<SPACE>`, which means I must backspace and type the slash if I want to continue. This makes me cry.

The changes seem to be located in the function `_longopt()` in `/etc/bash_completion`, however that is as far as I can follow. Is this change intentional, and if so, what is it good for? Can I have the old behaviour back, preferably by a config option instead of just copying the old code over from some other system?

Edit: The function for reference.

```
_longopt()
{
    local cur prev split=false
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n = cur prev

    _split_longopt && split=true

    case "$prev" in
        --*[Dd][Ii][Rr]*)
            _filedir -d
            return 0
            ;;
        --*[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee]*|--*[Pp][Aa][Tt][Hh]*)
            _filedir
            return 0
            ;;
    esac

    $split && return 0

    if [[ "$cur" == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( $1 --help 2>&1 | \
            sed -ne 's/.*\(--[-A-Za-z0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p' | sort -u )" \
            -- "$cur" ) )
    elif [[ "$1" == @(mk|rm)dir ]]; then
        _filedir -d
    else
        _filedir
    fi
}
```

Comment: The only way I could see that this would make sense is if ~/Desktop is a file or an *empty* directory. And in the second case, that's only useful for commands like `rmdir`, not for `mkdir` or `touch`.

Comment: Could you post the body of your `_longopt()` function?

Comment: @MPi: be aware that completion could depends on the command (first word of the command line). Also it can depends on `readline` settings (have you a `~/inputrc` file?) and on the fact that the item is a real directory or a symlink to a directory.

Comment: Of course the completion depends on the first word of the line. Which is why I sometimes use a fantasy command to trick completion, and only change it to the real command before I send it. And I have no `.inputrc` on this system anymore. (Those were the days, fixing backspace and cursor keys…) And it happens for all elements, directory or file, symlink or not.

Comment: Excellent question, I've observed the exact same behaviour, and it annoys me. No idea about the reason, though.

Comment: omg.  this has been driving me crazy.  thanks everyone on this question!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a known bug. See [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+question/155411) LP question and these bugs [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/775386) [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/769866).

[This comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/769866/comments/10) seems to be the fix.  If you can't wait for a fix to trickle down the normal channels, edit `/etc/bash_completion` line 1587, change `default` to `filenames` (make a backup first).

Comment: Summary: It is a bug, you can fix it locally until the patch arrives by editing `/etc/bash_completion` line 1587, change `default` to `filenames`.

Comment: edited my anwer

Comment: The comment that you've linked to no longer exists. Is your answer a complete summary of the linked solution?

Comment: The bug got transferred to another package; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866/comments/10 but confirm that this is still relevant, probably a lot of things have changed in the meantime

Answer (score 9):

I had, and solved, the same problem after installing Adobe Reader on Ubuntu 12.04.

I commented out the `_filedir` block in `/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh` and it worked normally again.

Comment: As of today's date this is what worked for me as well.

Comment: Same here: acroread triggered it and commenting out the `_filedir` block (right on top) fixed it.  You have to log out or run 'exec bash' in all your shells to see the effect, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52342/refresh-bash-tab-completion).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory, then reinstall bash_completion. I guess an old file was in this directory...
Hopefully it will solve your problem too.

Comment: like this guy: http://timlabath.com/words/2011/05/10/ubuntu-11-04-and-broken-bash-completion/

Comment: This – indeed – fixed it. However, that method es much too radical, as it throws away many completions. After deleting the package `bash-completion`, one of the files remaining `/etc/bash_completion.d/` must be the culprit. It was `acroread.sh` in my case – it redefines `_filedir`.